# Google Maps with Richmarker, Richmarker click fires map click aswell?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I just created a Google map with a Richmarker ( http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/examples/richmarker.html ).

Works fine except if i bind a onclick event to the marker, like:

> google.maps.event.addListener(add_button, 'click', function(event) {

... a click on the richmarker will also trigger this event on the underlying map:

> google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

Any idea how i can prevent Richmarker clicks to fire map clicks? Or is this a limitation with the Richmarker class perhaps?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Thank you, but i don't have any easy exctractable code and i solved it with a regular marker instead now. Seems to be some bug with RM.